# redirect if no query entered

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

People are accessing a page http...../property-verification/ which should only be accessed if a query result is provided from a search form on my homepage. e.g. http...../property-verification/?estimate_adr=value

I would like to redirect anyone accessing where no values are given for ?estimate_adr to my homepage.

All I could find for this is to add the following to my .htaccess page however, it doesn't seem to work.

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /\ HTTP'
RedirectMatch 307 ^/$ http......com/property-verification/
RewriteRule / http..........com/ [R=307]
```

Is there a way to do this through php or what changes need to be made to this?

Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

You must do this test before you output anything to the browser or it will fail with output already started.

```
if (!isset($_REQUEST['estimate_adr'])||empty($_REQUEST['estimate_adr'])){
header('Location: '.$newURL);
die();
}
```

Comment: that give me the following error: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/...../themes/....-child/header-33.php:2) in /home/....../themes/.....-child/header-33.php on line 151

Comment: You need to ensure you don't output anything before calling the header() function. Put the code earlier in your script. _Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include, or require, functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file._ (http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: Thanks - the redirect works now if NOTHING is entered. But now if something IS entered i get the "Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by ....." The scipt is located at the top of the header